# why input and label elements got change automatically on development instance

Tags: html, jenkins, deployment

Here is my code

```
<input class="input-radio" data-pid="${pdict.Product.ID}" type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="shipToStore" id="ship-shop-${pdict.Product.ID}" />
<label for="ship_to_store">
```

But when this code goes to develop environment it's reflecting like

```
<input class="input-radio" data-pid="10775895" type="radio" checked="checked" name="shippingMethod" value="shipToStore" id="ship-shop-10775895" data-ae-form-field="true">
<label for="ship-shop-10775895" class="ae-label">
```

Can you please help me to find out

1. From where this `data-ae-form-field="true"` is coming ?
2. Why my label for attribute value got change automatically (There is
   no js written for this, already checked whole js part).
3. Why it's adding class to my label `class="ae-label"`

Comment: How are you deploying the code?

Comment: ohhhh...that I am not aware exactly. There different team who is deploying this. But for sure using Jenkins

Comment: It almost certainly has something to do with that deployment process, this isn't something that happens just when copying files.

Comment: Do you know any third party library or something which uses this 'ae-' attributes ?

Comment: I've never seen it before.

Comment: the value in the `for` attribute of a label is supposed to be the ID of the associated form field. There's no `id="ship_to_store"`. Looks like the deployment script fixed it to have the ID of the input field instead of its value.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But if some developer don't want to bind label text with radio button then it's totally fine. The question is from where it's getting changed

Comment: I'm guessing the `ae` stuff is some kind of framework or library like bootstrap.

Comment: You need to check the deployment scripts, it's obviously happening there.

Comment: Regarding bootstrap thing..it's there on local instance as well but it works fine on local. Anyway thanks Bro!. I really need to check this with deployment script. Thanks for your efforts